# Current Timestamp with ORMLite?

Tags: java, ormlite

When I insert a date in my my table using ORMLite I usually do something like this:

```
@DatabaseField(dataType=DataType.DATE_STRING, format="yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
private Date MatchDate;
```

What if I want something like

```
ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the custom SQL to create the field using the [`@DatabaseField` `columnDefinition` field](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#columnDefinition()).

```
@DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.DATE_STRING, format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
      columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Date MatchDate;
```

Another option would be to make the schema yourself if you need more control.  You can get the create table statements from [TableUtils.getCreateTableStatements()](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/table/TableUtils.html#getCreateTableStatements%28com.j256.ormlite.support.ConnectionSource,%20java.lang.Class%29) method and then you will have to tune them to adjust for the `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, etc..

You can execute raw SQL with the `dao.executeSql("...")` method.  Here are the [javadocs for this method](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/dao/Dao.html#executeRaw%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String...%29).

Here's a link to the documentation of what [raw SQL statements](http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-statements) you can execute in ORMLite.

Comment: i'm sorry. I meant in field definition of a table, not a row.

Comment: Does my response not answer your question @dierre?  Is the `ts` command not a one time thing?

Comment: ts is the name of a field inside the definition of a table.

Comment: Oh sorry.  So you need to tune the schema generated by ORMLite?

Comment: exactly. I think I can ovveride default by setting defaultValue="CURRENT_TIMESTAMP" but I don't know how to add the "update part".

Comment: Tnx, but that seems the logical solution, I'll go raw on it ;)

Comment: Another question I was wondering about - what is the default value for  DataType.DATE_STRING? The doc doesn't say anything except: Persists the Date Java class as a string of a format. NOTE: This is not the same as the Date class. How would I set the default value (If it's null at the time of persistence/retrieval) to null? Because default = "null" doesnt work.

Comment: @Zainodis In the future, please use the mailing list for these sorts of questions.  Asking in comments is not appropriate.  The default value should be null.  Let me know if it isn't.

Comment: @Gray: Sorry, thought it wasn't worth spamming the mailing list :) anyway, my bad, the default is indeed null.